# Gii with no css/js

Tags: php, javascript, css, yii, gii

I'm trying to use Yii's automated code generation tool Gii, but it is trying to reference a bunch of CSS and JS files that does not exist. I have tried multiple times from scratch and setting the permissions each time. It seems as the files are not being generated, however, the cryptic named folders do get generated. How can i fix this? I can't find ANYone with the same problem.

Here's a screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/zZkuKGo7

Any help or pointers in the right direction will be very much appreciated.

Comment: delete all the contents of asset folder and try.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to load those CSS urls directly in the browser.
- Go to the file system in a shell or sftp and look if they exist in the assets folder.
- Clear assets like commenter suggested.
- Check document root setting for virtual host in the web server config.
- Check for htaccess rules that would prevent access to those files.
- Look in web server access logs for details.
- Unzip a fresh Yii directly on the server so all permissions are set automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete all folders in /assets/, and yii regenerate it.